# Appium switching context to web view

Tags: android, automation, appium

I'm trying to automate android application using APPIUM, but it's not able to switch context to web view.
I found out that the activity having the web view has process attribute, and I think this causes the problem.
To prove it, I created simple apps. One has process attribute, the other one doesn't.

I'm using APPIUM GUI 1.4.13 and chrome driver 2.21

Can anybody advise?

The failing log:

```
info: Chromedriver: Changed state to 'stopped'

error: Chromedriver: Chromedriver exited unexpectedly with code null, signal SIGTERM

warn: Chromedriver for context WEBVIEW_com.linecorp.appiumwebviewsample:account stopped unexpectedly
warn: Chromedriver quit unexpectedly, but it wasn't the active context, ignoring

error: Chromedriver: Error: An error occurred (Original error: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.4 x86_64))
    at JWProxy.command$ (lib/proxy.js:149:15)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:294:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.runBound (domain.js:267:12)
    at run (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:89:39)
    at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:100:28
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
 { [Error: An error occurred (Original error: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.4 x86_64))]
  status: 100,
  value: { message: 'chrome not reachable\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.4 x86_64)' },
  httpCode: 200 }
```

Comment: seems to be another one of appium Vs chrome-driver issue

Answer (score 0):

I could find the similar message when app package Desired Capability is not set. 
Are you using com.android.chrome as the appPackage?

Comment: I set it as my android app's package. Should I set it as chrome?

Comment: Try using the appPackage as com.android.chrome